How to test Salesforce Sites Error Pages
I override the standard error pages for a Salesforce Site (Not Found, In Maintenance, Generic Error) with my own Visualforce pages.
How I can test In Maintenance and Generic Error pages?
I tried to throw an exception in methods on other vf pages, but instead of redirecting to the Generic Error page, the current page reloads. See only FATAL_ERROR in debug logs.

According to this article, to preview the pages you can simply navigate to:
Setup > Sites > Name of your Site
From the Site Details page, you can simply select 'Preview' to see the page you have assigned to that particular error scenario.

I mean real situation.
Generic Error Page—The page users see when encountering generic exceptions.
I didn't find an exception that falls into the group generic exceptions
The Visualforce Developer Guide does not mention exceptions at all.
